# Weird error: wait_fences: failed to receive reply: 10004003

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimagepickercontroller

I know that there are other questions that deal with this error, but those answers don't help me any. I was wondering if anyone knew the exact cause, and if no one does, here is the code:

```
-(void) imagePickerController : (UIImagePickerController *) picker
        didFinishPickingImage : (UIImage *) image
                  editingInfo : (NSDictionary *) editingInfo {

    self.imageView.image = image;
    [picker dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [picker release];
    //[self myNextResponder];
}
```

This error: wait_fences: failed to receive reply: 10004003, appears right after this method exits. I have googled all over, and cannot figure it out.

Comment: I'm having the same issue... any luck with it? It's so strange!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It appears that you used the picker object as the caller of present/dismissModalViewController.  The documentation recommends using the "parent" view controller.

For the "parent" I used self.navigationController (since it won't be going anywhere)

The implementation of my picker delegate's cancel method looks like this...

```
- (void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker
{
    // make sure the picker doesn't try to access the soon to die delegate
    picker.delegate = nil;

    [self.navigationController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply comment the line

//[picker release];

and try

Comment: This will lead a memory leak.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you don't have any keyboards shown up on the screen.
Use [yourTextFieldOrTextView resignFirstResponder] if you have. 
Thanks